# Multiple insances of a custum field for one entity

Tags: civicrm-home

How do I implement a custom field where I can input multiple instances of that thing.

For example I want to add Hobby custom field to Contacts. But a person can have more than one hobby. Is there  a way I click add another hobby, and then another etc.

Is there a way to add an arbitrary number instances of the same filed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not so much the field you set to multiple, it is the custom group! So for example, many contracts.[image]

You can add multiple custom fields for contacts ONLY (including individuals, orgnaizations and households). You need to check the box **Does this Custom Field Set allow multiple records?** (see attached screen print) and then you can add multiple hobbies.

Comment: Thx for the quick answer. That is what I was looking for, but I don't need it for Contact, I need it for Contributions. I just used Contacts and hobbies as an example. Ís there a way to enable multiple records for Contributions?

Comment: You can not use this feature for contributions i am afraid. What you could do is use either a comma separated array or values in between CRM_Core_DAO::VALUE_SEPARATORS? But that would require some coding.